# RxJs chaining observables with subscriptions

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, request-queueing

I have a form which consists of blocks which are retrieved by calls to API.

I need to process each call accordingly to that specific call (I'm creating a formGroup part based on that call).

What I want is to have some kind of global observable/status which will be completed when all calls are made and processed.

Now I'm doing it by creating a BehaviorSubject counter and on each request I increment this. When this counter reaches some value I change `loading` to `false` and show a form then. Is there a better way?

It looks like

```
o1.subscribe(() => {... this.counter.next(this.counter.value + 1) });
o2.subscribe(() => {... this.counter.next(this.counter.value + 1) });
o3.subscribe(() => {... this.counter.next(this.counter.value + 1) });
```

.

```
this.counter.subscribe(val => if (val === 3) { this.loading = false; }
```

I've thought of creating `of()` wrapper and using `concat()` around them but I don't think that it's right.

Comment: concat should work if order is a concern, why do you think that's not right?

Comment: @ABOS first of all it chains all methods and makes them in order, meanwhile I could benefit from simultaneous requests. Moreover it's an observable of observable result which doesn't seem right.

Comment: if order is not a concern, you can use forkJoin.

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me. You may post it as an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order is not a concern, you can use forkJoin from rxjs, which works similar to Promise.all,

```
 forkJoin([...requests])
   .subscribe(_ => this.loading = false;)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use the forkjoin from RxJs

[Plunker Demo link](https://plnkr.co/edit/ElTrOg8NfR3WbbAfjBXQ?p=preview)

```
 ngOnInit() {
    forkJoin(
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request One', 2000),
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Two', 1000) 
      this._myService.makeRequest('Request Three', 3000) 
    )
    .subscribe(([res1, res2, res3]) => {
      this.propOne = res1;
      this.propTwo = res2;
      this.propThree = res3;
    });
  }
```

[Ref from :](http://%20https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)